# Why do you have to specify an index number when assigning a value to the first element in an array?

Tags: c++, c

Why do you have to specify an index number when assigning a value to the first element in an array?
Let's say we had this array:

```
int childer[] = {10, 30, 50};
```

then both `childer` and `childer[0]` would be accessing the first element of the array, so why can't you do`childer = 15;`?

Comment: What makes you say `childer` would be accessing the first element of the array?

Comment: It will be evaluated to the first element, right? @Angew

Comment: Do you mean `*childer`?

Comment: @Jake No, it won't be. Array is an array, element is an element.

Comment: No. It will be a pointer to the first element. Not the same thing.

Comment: @SimonKraemer, yea I think, but I ´have probably confused myself a little... What I mean is that childer is sort of pointing to the first element which also is why when you assign the array to a pointer like int* pointer=childer;, it would point to the first element... And isn't childer[] also pointing to the first element? I really think that I have mixed something together that I should not have...

Comment: `childer[]` doesn't point anywhere, the `[]` is just part if the declaration.

Comment: `childer` is not accessing the first element of the array.  `childer` is an array.  In _some_ contexts, like `foo(childer)`, the address of the first element of `childer` is passed to `foo()`, yet `childer` remains an array.

Comment: @JesperJuhl, It will not be a pointer, it will be a reference (a read only address value) as it cannot be modified. The array identifier is interpreted in an expression as a pointer value (not a pointer) of type `T * const` pointing to the first element of the array.

Answer (score 5):

Arrays are similar to pointers. For example an array decays to a pointer when passed to a function, or even when the operators `[]` and the unary `*` are applied to them (Thanks StoryTeller). So

```
childer[0]
```

is equivalent to

```
*childer
```

and you can do

```
*childer = 15;
```

to set the first element to 15.

---

```
childer
```

on the other hand is the same as

```
&childer[0]
```

Comment: They decay more often than just as function arguments. `[]` and unary `*` are in fact defined **only** for pointer operands. The array decays before the arithmetic is preformed.

Comment: Arrays are not similar to pointers. They are fundamentally extremely different. What is true is that an array expression undergoes implicit conversion into a pointer to the first element in many contexts.

Comment: Ahh thanks! So it would be valid to say that an array without the [] operators is pointing to the first element and technically works just like a pointer/is a pointer and therefore you have to dereference it in order to access the actual element?

Comment: @davmac so why is it a pointer and not just a non-pointer type? And if they work just like pointers then, why can't you reassign them then?

Comment: @Jake no. An array is an array, it isn't pointing to anything. An array value is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element in various contexts (which do not include OP's intended use), but not all of these contexts require `[]` to be used. In fact there are only a small number of contexts where the conversion doesn't happen implicitly. But note _is converted to_. That does not mean they are the same thing; it means one is produced out of the other.

Comment: @Jake _And if they work just like pointers then, why can't you reassign them then?_ - because they don't, and because the conversion from array to pointer doesn't happen in the context of assignment, and because arrays are designed as "non-modifiable lvalues" by the standard which means that assignment isn't allowed. (As to why the standard doesn't permit assigning one array to another equal-sized array of the same component type, I couldn't tell you!).

Comment: as per discussion on another answer, the array-to-pointer conversion may actually occur in the context of OP's question (referred to as "in the context of assignment" in previous comment) - however, it doesn't ultimately affect the answer or anything else I've said here. I hope it's clear.

Comment: @davmac wow thank you so much! It really makes sense when you think of it in that way. But is there a place where I can read more about this implicit conversion and the other great information you gave? I have read about both arrays and pointers though...

Comment: @Jake the authoritative source is the C language standard itself (eg draft here: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1548.pdf). However, it's not particularly easy reading and it's full of traps for the casual reader. The relevant section to this discussion though is 6.3.2.1, paragraph 3: _Except  when  it  is  the  operand  of  [various],  an  expression  that  has  type  ‘‘array  of type’’  is converted to an expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points to the initial element of the  array  object  and  is  not  an  lvalue._

Answer (score 0):

`childer[0]` and `childer` have two different meanings. `childer[0]` is the **first element** of the array while `childer` is a **pointer to the first element**. In order to get the first element using the pointer, you have to use `*childer`.

so,

```
*childer = 15;
```

can be used for assignment.

Comment: `childer` is not a pointer to the first element. `childer` is the array itself. It is implicitly converted into a pointer to the first element in many, but certainly not all, contexts. Eg if your statement was true then `sizeof(childer) == sizeof(&childer[0])` would necessarily be true, but it is not.

Comment: yeah, I was referring to the implicit conversion which he is asking about. thanks @devmac for his great input.

Comment: @davmac It doesn't matter if it is on the left-hand-side of an assignment or not. `foo[bar]` is equivalent to `(*((foo)+(bar)))` in any expression. For example, `0[childer] = 15;` is a perfectly legal assignment, but it wouldn't make sense unless arrays decayed to pointers in this sort of expression.

Comment: @IanAbbot In your example `foo` does not occur on the left-hand-side of an assignment, it appears as the subject of the `[ ]` operator and this compound expression is then on the left-hand-side of the assignment. See OP's example: _why can't you do childer = 15;_ - in this, `childer` appears directly on the lhs of `=` and the standard explicitly says that in this case it will not undergo the implicit conversion. Being the subject of `[x]` is a context where the conversion applies, yes - I didn't say it wasn't.

Comment: @davmac I get what you mean now. My stuff about the array indexing is irrelevant. However, C11 section 6.3.2.1 paragraph 3 implies that an array object on the l.h.s of an assignment is still converted to a pointer, but is no longer an _lvalue_ after the conversion. So by strict interpretation of the standard, it is converted, but since the conversion results in an illegal assignment expression (because the l.h.s. is not a _modifiable lvalue_), it's really just semantics.

Comment: @IanAbbott looking at it again I've mixed it up with the previous paragraph in the spec (which specifically mentions lhs of assignment). You're right, the conversion occurs (and it's no longer an lvalue). (And as you say, this doesn't make much difference - you can't assign to it either way).

Answer (score 0):

you could dereference the name of the array, but just trying to do

```
childer = -999;
```

is completely wrong...

see the example below:

```
int main() {
    int childer[] = { 10, 30, 50 };
    cout << childer[0] << endl;
    cout << *childer << endl;
    //now write
    childer[0] = 200;
    cout << childer[0] << endl;
    cout << *childer << endl;
    //now write again
    *childer = -999;
    cout << childer[0] << endl;
    cout << *childer << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all

```
int childer[] = { 10, 20, 30 };
...
childer = ....; <--- THIS WILL NOT COMPILE, as childer is not an lvalue.
```

you cannot say `childer = 20;`, you can say `childer[0] = 20;` or `*childer = 20;`, or even more `*(childer + 1) = 20;` (to access other elements than the first), but you cannot use `childer` as the whole array in an assignment.  Simply, neither *C* nor *C++* allow this.

Arrays and pointers *are very different things.*  What confuses you, is that neither **C**, nor **C++** have a way to reference the array as a whole, and the array identifier, by itself, **means the address of the first element** (and not a pointer but a reference).  What I mean by *a reference*, and I don't use the word pointer for just now, is that a pointer normally refers to *a variable of pointer type*, and as a variable, can be modified (mainly because the array position cannot be changed at runtime).  You cannot write something like `array = something_else;`, when `array` is an array.  Array names cannot be used by themselves as lvalues, only as rvalues.  This can be done with pointers, like

```
int childer[] = { 10, 20, 30, };
int *pointer = childer;
```

and then

```
pointer = some_other_place_to_point_to;
```

because `pointer` is a pointer and `childer` isn't.

The meaning that both languages attribute to the array name is just *a pointer rvalue pointing to the address of the first element* (and typed as the cell type, continue reading for an explanation on this).   And this is not the same as the address of the array (both are different things, demonstrated below) as the first (the array name is a pointer to cell type, while the array address `&childer` is a pointer to the whole array type).  This can be illustrated with the next program, which tries to show you the difference in sizes for the array element, the whole array, the array pointer and the cell pointer:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#define D(x) __FILE__":%d:%s: " x, __LINE__, __func__

#define P(fmt, exp) do { \
        printf(D(#exp " == " fmt "\n"), (exp)); \
    } while(0)
#define TR(sent) \
    sent; \
    printf(D(#sent ";\n"))

int main()
{
    int i = 1;
    TR(double a[10]);

    P("%p", a);
    P("%p", &a);
    P("%d", sizeof a);
    P("%d", sizeof &a);
    P("%d", sizeof *a);
    P("%d", sizeof *&a);

    return 0;
}
```

which executes into (I selected `double` as the type of cell to make evident the differences while trying to be more architecture independent):

```
$ pru
pru.c:16:main: double a[10];    <-- array of ten double's (a double is 8 bytes in many architectures)
pru.c:18:main: a == 0xbfbfe798  <-- address values are
pru.c:19:main: &a == 0xbfbfe798 <--    equal for both.
pru.c:20:main: sizeof a == 80   <-- size of whole array.
pru.c:21:main: sizeof &a == 4   <-- size of array address (that's a pointer to array)
pru.c:22:main: sizeof *a == 8   <-- size of pointed cell (first array element)
pru.c:23:main: sizeof *&a == 80 <-- size of pointed array.
```

But you are wrong when saying that you cannot use an expression to access the other elements, as you can, use `array + 1` to mean the address of the second element, and `array + n` to access the address of the `n + 1` element.  Evidently `array + 0` is the same as `array` (the `0` number is also neutral in pointer addition), so you can get on it easily.  Some people like to write it for fun also as `0+array` (to abuse of the commutativity of the `+` operator) and go further, to write something like `0[array]`, to refer to the first element of the array (this time the access being to the element, and not to its address)  I don't know if this continues to be valid with the new standards, but I'm afraid it continues, perhaps, to allow for legacy code to be compilable (adding to the controversy of what should be conserved and what can be eliminated on standard revisions)

Comment: _Array names cannot be used by themselves as lvalues, only as rvalues_ - technically this is not true, they can (at least in C) be "non-modifiable lvalues". This matters when you want to take the address of an array, since you can't take the address of an rvalue.

Comment: @davmac, when you take the address... as when you dereference a pointer, the rvalue converts in an lvalue, as in `array[3] = 0;`, `array` by itself is not an lvalue, but `array[3]` is.  What I mean is that an array (which is something well defined in C) cannot be the target of an assignation (which is the definition of lvalue).  The address of an array is not the array itself, so it is not the same thing.  In pascal, for example, you can assign arrays as you do with `struct`s in C.  A `struct` variable can be a lvalue, an array cannot.

Comment: _What I mean is that an array (which is something well defined in C) cannot be the target of an assignation (which is the definition of lvalue)_ No, that's not the definition of lvalue. _Unmodifiable lvalues_ cannot be assigned to. An array name by itself is an unmodifiable lvalue - you can take its address (which is what lvalue really means; more formally, it _designates an object_). You say _`array` by itself is not an lvalue_ but that's wrong, it is an unmodifiable lvalue. See C11 6.5.1 - an identifier referring to an object is an lvalue (even if it is an array).

Comment: Also 6.3.2.1: _A modifiable lvalue is an lvalue that does  not  have  array  type_ - i.e. an lvalue can have array type, but it won't then be a _modifiable_ lvalue.